# Apache RewriteCond to Lighttpd

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighty

I want to migrate some sites running on apache to Lighttpd.

Can anyone help me to convert this Rewrite rule into a equivalent rule for Lighttpd:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I'm reading the Lighttpd rewrite explanation (http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite) but I didn't understand how convert this specific rule.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The Apache rules you list [use RewriteCond to take any request](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond) which doesn't go to a direcotyr (!-d) and which also doesn't go to a file (!-f) and redirects it to pass the URL data into index.php as parameter "url".  It makes sure to preserve any other CGI arguments (QSA) and makes no further rules match if this rule matches (L).

So `http://yourserver.org/something-silly` would go to `http://yourserver.org/index.ph?url=something-silly` and `http://yourserver.org/something-silly?q=search+terms` would go to `http://yourserver.org/index.ph?url=something-silly&q=search-terms`

[Lighttpd has url.rewrite-if-not-file](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs%3AModRewrite#urlrewrite-repeat-if-not-file) which partially implements this, but it will rewrite  URL if it's a directory.  Therefore, you'll have to add rules to specifically NOT rewrite URLs that go to known valid directories.